# How to create insert query with multiple values in python for postgresql

Tags: python, dataframe, list-comprehension, insert-update, timescaledb

I have datas in df like

| time | location | information |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.13 | India | Good |
| 2.34 | USA | Good |

I need to update this to timescale db where time is the unique key, i have used

```
    list_db_df=df.values.tolist()
```

Now this turned into a list of values like

```
[[2.13,India,Good],[2.34,USA,Good]]
```

How do i write this for insert query like this,

```
INSERT INTO table_name
  VALUES
    (NOW(), 'office', 70.0, 50.0),
    (NOW(), 'basement', 66.5, 60.0),
    (NOW(), 'garage', 77.0, 65.2);
```

Basically this format

https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/write-data/insert/#insert

And need help with on conflict clause ([Example](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/write-data/upsert/#upsert-functionality))

```
INSERT INTO table_name
  VALUES ('2017-07-28 11:42:42.846621+00', 'office', 70.2, 50.1)
  ON CONFLICT (time, location) DO UPDATE
    SET temperature = excluded.temperature,
        humidity = excluded.humidity;
```

Like, what is **excluded.temperature** there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with **I need to update this to timescaledb**? So the table already exists and you want to "convert" it to a hypertable? i.e. see [Create hypertables](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/hypertables/create/)

Comment: No just to update the row with these df values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short

Quote from the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

> The SET and WHERE clauses in ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE have access to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and to rows proposed for insertion using the special excluded table.

In your example, `excluded.temperature` has the value `70.2`

## Details

See also [DbFiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cd58c9529a01148073420e7a5631c5c4):

Let's assume, that the table already has a row with this primary key (`'2017-07-28 11:42:42.846621+00'`, `office`):

| time | location | temperature | humidity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-07-28 12:42:42.846621+01 | office | 60.1 | 50 |

Now we execute an insert statements (with the same primary key) and different `ON CONFLICT` clauses

### No `ON CONFLICT` clause

```
INSERT INTO conditions VALUES ('2017-07-28 11:42:42.846621+00', 'office', 70.2, 50.1)
```

When we do not use `ON CONFLICT`, we get an error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "conditions_time_location_key"
DETAIL:  Key ("time", location)=(2017-07-28 12:42:42.846621+01, office) already exists.
```

### ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING

```
INSERT INTO conditions 
VALUES ('2017-07-28 11:42:42.846621+00', 'office', 70.2, 50.1)
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

In this case the new data is ignored and the row remains the same as before:

| time | location | temperature | humidity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-07-28 12:42:42.846621+01 | office | 60.1 | 50 |

### ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE

example:

```
INSERT INTO conditions 
VALUES ('2017-07-28 11:42:42.846621+00', 'office', 70.2, 50.1)
ON CONFLICT (time, location) DO UPDATE
    SET humidity = excluded.temperature;
```

will result in:

| time | location | temperature | humidity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-07-28 12:42:42.846621+01 | office | 60.1 | 70.2 |

NOTE: that we assign `humidity` to `excluded.temperature` - this does not really make sense in a production app, and is only used to illustrate how this works

When we use `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`, we have access to a special table named `exclude`.
This table contains the values from our insert statement that have been excluded (i.e. ignored), because other values already exist.

In our case:

- `excluded.temperature` is `70.2`
- `excluded.humidity` is `50.1`

When you do no use `SET` for a column, the column keeps the old value: i.e. the `temperature` will still be `60.1` after our insert statement.

When you do use `SET` for a column you can assign any value you like: e.g. a constant value, an expression, or the values from the special `excluded` table which contains the excluded row.

Comment: This is clearly explaining the usage.

Comment: So how do i convert list of list to insert query in that

Comment: I don't know pandas, but maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38610751/1041641